# How can I add category variable inside posts?

Tags: customization, templates, categories

I want to add a category variable along with the date variable that post has been published.

For example, when I go to a post, I see the following under the post title:

```
last updated on May 10, 2019
```

I want to add the category name that this article has been posted to. For example, if I add this post under **news category**, it will show the category along with date as a link for this category:

```
last updated on May 10, 2019 in news
```

So far I know the code that we should modify in templates-tags.php file especially:

```
printf(
                '<span class="posted-on">last updated on %1$s</span><span class="byline"> <i class="fa fa-user"></i> %2$s</span> in ',
                sprintf(
                    '<a href="%1$s" rel="bookmark">%2$s</a>',
                    esc_url( get_permalink() ),
                    $time_string
                ),
                sprintf(
                    '<span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="%1$s">%2$s</a></span>',
                    esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ),
                    esc_html( get_the_author() )
                )
            );
    }
endif;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`get_the_category_list()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category_list), which returns a list of categories assigned to the post (each category in the list links to the category archive):

```php
printf(
    '<span class="posted-on">last updated on %1$s</span><span class="byline"> <i class="fa fa-user"></i> %2$s</span> in %3$s',
    sprintf(
        '<a href="%1$s" rel="bookmark">%2$s</a>',
        esc_url( get_permalink() ),
        $time_string
    ),
    sprintf(
        '<span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="%1$s">%2$s</a></span>',
        esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ),
        esc_html( get_the_author() )
    ),
    get_the_category_list( ', ' )
);
```

Comment: thank you it actually works! however, there is just two space between the **date** and **in** word do you know how to remove just one space between the date and in word?

Comment: the temporary solution i did is to make css for the category and with the following css variable settings
`.category-post {
  margin-left: -4px;
 }` that eliminates the double space between the date and in word but i don't know if this a good solution or there is something to fix really simple than that but i am not aware about it

Comment: Maybe that's more to a CSS issue. If you can share the page URL, I could probably look at the issue - and help fix it in a better/quicker way. Or if you can't share it, then does the issue happen to all posts having the `<span class="posted-on">...</span>` tag (or element)? Can you inspect the page source/HTML and copy one of those elements? (I mean, copy the HTML markup)